# Bluetooth Low Energy Discovery on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

It seem Bluetooth Low Energy (aka Bluetooth Smart) has no official support on Android, even version 4.2.  Anyone know if the standard Android API can discovery BLE devices?  (I don't need pairing just discovery would be good)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT 2:** Seems like my lucky day is today ;) : [new link](http://android-btle.github.io/framework/)
**EDIT:** Seems like today is your lucky day: [Open Source API](https://code.google.com/p/broadcom-ble/)

I guess this answer is not adequate, but it is: on some devices yes, on others no.
A company I worked for did some testing with it and they could pair in on a Galaxy S3 while my HTC One S didn't even discover it.

So if a manufacturer has implemented this feature it will work, but most times it won't.

Some discussion about this: [Texas Instruments](http://e2e.ti.com/support/low_power_rf/f/538/t/240097.aspx)

Comment: Seems like lucky day is already gone cause OpenSourceAPI link to code of broadcom-ble is not working.. ;(

Answer (score 2):

It is correct that Android took a switch from Bluez -> Broadcom Bluetooth. This switch was causing lots of problems for Android users. Missing BT classic profiles and Wifi v.s. BT coexistence (one probably reset the other since they are in the same chipset in most phones). iPhone and MAC computers suffer a lot from the same problem (BT v.s. Wifi).

The Broadcom Open Source Low Energy API was not included in 4.2.

HTC One X+ got slightly modified (?) Broadcom BLE API on top of Bluez in 4.1.x and it works reasonably good though I have to retry connection sometimes. The package name is htc not broadcom but sometimes Eclipse error messages tells that it is missing some broadcom references.
Also Samsung got a "secret" API for BT BLE with their own package name which can discover devices but seems to be not really robust (which may be why it is "secret")

Google have officially said that "BLE is the next big thing we will release". So maybe in Android 5.0? but hopefully before so Galaxy S2 (which have such a big marketshare and uses the same chipset as iPhone 4s) can get BLE support. (Just speculations and hopes from my side). If Android 5.0 get's BLE API's then Samsung Galaxy S3 should get it as Samsung has listed this as getting Android 5.0.

Only time or Google will tell... It's way overtime getting this old Nokia Research Center technology out in other than Meego and iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a standard api will be coming to Android api 18 http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/05/15/bluetooth-low-energy-and-avrcp-1-3-coming-to-android-with-api-level-18/

Comment: It has come: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

Answer (score 0):

Devices with the relevant hardware will work with Android 4.3.x support.  I just put a Galaxy S2 GT-I9100 to 4.3.1 Slimbean and can now pair it with a Bluetooth 4.0 LE/Smart heart rate monitor.  This, in spite of the stock hardware only ever supporting BT 3.0+, according to Samsung.